# should we include or exclude a variable in a logistic regression based on the description below?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, predictive-models

should we include or exclude a variable in a logit regr. model which will only obtain values if a certain event takes place otherwise will show N/A? this variable tells whether or not a product will be bought based on calls made by the company. the variable tells: number of days that passed by after the client was last contacted from a previous campaign. the values (-1) are for users who were not previously contacted
[image]

Comment: It could be possible that the not being contacted has an effect on the response. As a result, I wouldn't suggest dropping the variable. You could try transforming it into categories (e.i. [contacted (Yes/No)] or [contacted (No, 0-100 days, 100-200 days, 200-300 days, 300+ days)] - these are two possible options, out of many you, could explore.

Comment: adding to what @nwaldo said, you may also try taking zero as a value for "No", in which case the effect on the resulting regression is likewise zero

Comment: @AndreasSteimer thank you for the help. also wanted to ask if the changing to numerical forms is necessary before fitting the logit reg model?https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/461535/is-the-data-riady-to-fit-the-logistic-regression-model